# How to remove rows in a DataFrame that contain numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file that contains a few thousand rows, one column contains text values which  sometimes are numbers. If the message column, in the example below, contains a number I want to remove the entire row.

The file is read in as a CSV, the table is a dataFrame, how I check if the message is a number and if it is then remove the entire row?

This is the original table:

| name | message |
| --- | --- |
| John | Hello |
| Steve | 25 |
| Jane | Hi |
| Janet | 89 |

I'd like it to look like this:

| name | message |
| --- | --- |
| John | Hello |
| Jane | Hi |

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `str.contains` with the invert operator:

```
>>> df[~df['message'].str.contains('\d+')]
   name message
0  John   Hello
2  Jane      Hi
>>>
```